# Using one electrical pump for multiple hoses

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pumps, valves, compressed-air

I'm currently trying to figure out a cheap way to build a cocktail machine. 
For now the machine should have about 20-30 possible input liquids. These liquids should remain in their original bottle and should electrically be pumped up when needed. (I know I could use gravity instead of pumps, but the bottles should be stored in a cabinet under the machine itself.)

At first I was looking for a good type of pump to use for this project and I think peristaltic pumps would be ideal because then I could be sure that the liquids haven't come in contact with anything but the hose.

Then I tried to find the cheapest pumps of this type available, but unfortunately the cheap ones are still about 5€ and they would only do 150ml/min. I think 500ml/min would be the absolute minimum required.

But now I'm thinking that maybe there is a cheaper way and I just don't know the components.

So my idea would be that maybe I could just buy one big pump (maybe [something like this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000175544443.html)) and then connect all 20-30 hoses to it using a bunch of adapters (maybe a bunch of [these](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32707672027.html)).
Then I would just need cheap way to electrically close all but one hose at a time. So I was wondering if there if some sort of electric valve that is very cheap (maybe 1-2€) and doesn't come into direct contact with the liquid. I was thinking maybe some sort of electromagnet that squishes the hose or a DC motor that uses some sort of screw mechanism to bend the hose until nothing can pass through anymore.
I should also mention that I'm going to use something like an ESP8266 or maybe an Arduino to control the whole machine.

Is there any such component?

**Edit:**
As suggested in the comments it might be a better idea to simply pump air into the bottles to get the liquid out. This way I can run completely separated hoses avoiding the problem that liquids may flow back into the wrong bottle (which would especially suck for milk and cream etc.).
I found really [cheap air valves](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000567064321.html) that I could use for this purpose. 
I could power/control them using a [relay board like this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000246379046.html) which I'd attach to an Arduino. Then I'd then just connect a compressor or CO2 container at a reasonable pressure to the valve input.
Sounds like this could work to me. But what if these valves aren't perfectly clean? I should probably have some sort of air filter behind each of these, right? Any ideas how I could accomplish that in a cheap way?

I have intention of using this machine commercially btw.

**Edit2:**
Another problem with the air idea is that I'd have to buy a compressor for that. And they are loud and expensive form what I can tell and besides that they are completely overkill. I doubt I'd even need a 1 bar of pressure. 
Is there maybe some sort of cheap low power (but therefore very quiet) compressor that I could use?

**Edit3:**
Could I build an air filter [like this one](https://www.instructables.com/id/Make-an-Air-Purifier-on-the-cheap/) but instead of using a PVC tube, simply use the hoses that go into the bottles?

**Edit4:** 
Bottles that are carbonated in the first place could be another challenge because they would just push out liquid automatically over time unless I build a mechanism that detaches the compressor and then opens all valves that that no bottle can build up pressure while the machine is idling.

**Edit5:**
Maybe a quiet fish tank air pump could be used instead of a compressor. 
I found some that are rated:
throughput: 192 liters / hour
power: 2 watts
pressure (MPa): >0.012
noise: < 40 db

I think 0.012 MPa would be 0.12 bars or 1.74 psi. But I have no understanding of how much that actually is and if it would be enough.

Comment: This question is about shopping for electrically actuated valves. The suitability appears to be determined by price and the suitability for use with liquids for human consumption. This is not an electrical engineering design or theory question. Voting to close.

Comment: The concept for pressurizing the liquids so that that the selected one flows when the related valve is open may need further development, but that is not an electrical problem either.

Comment: Cross contamination and purging are an issue. Voting closure.

Comment: I agree consider CO2 tank pressure regulator to suitable tanks

Comment: Not only that, but this brings with it a whole host of biological concerns. How long is grenadine, lets say, going to "be good" and "taste alright" in a valve?  What happens when it spoils, unbeknownst to the operator, and multiple people get sick?  I see a long road of legal battles a possibility.

Comment: Very cheap electrical pumps and valves are not certified to be used with human food or drinks. Ingredients used for the last drink should not be mixed with those for the next one. Cleaning the pump with some water would add unwanted water to the next drink. So the use of a single liquid pump is impossible anyway. To avoid cross contamination each hose should be used for a single ingredient only.

Comment: I'm thinking push air into the top of the bottle rather than pull liquid out of the bottom. Then your pump is pumping the same fluid (air) regardless of which liquid is being dispensed, and the liquid never touches the pump mechanism. But it does mean the system needs to maintain positive pressure at all times if the reservoirs are located below the dispense location.

Comment: Peristaltic pumps have a lot of disadvantages in this application. For example, the suction that they can develop is limited by the elastic characteristics of the tubing itself. There are many other ways to move food-grade fluids around. For example, if you can get an airtight seal on the bottles, you can use air pressure to move the fluids around, and the only thing in contact with them is a simple siphon tube. You just need a single air compressor and some simple electromagnetic air valves.

Comment: Gravity works well with a rotating valve to control the amount delivered

Comment: @Uwe I use certified hoses and since the pumps only push on the hoses by design they never come into contact with the liquid. This is not a commercial product btw and yes the hoses obviously need to get cleaned after a day of use.
The idea of having completely individual hoses and using air to force the liquids out of their bottles is very interesting. But I'd still need a bunch of electrically controllable air valves and probably a small air filter behind every valve would make sense.

Comment: Reminds me of this - [Drinking at the Bellagio](https://www.hotel-online.com/press_releases/release/drinking-at-the-bellagio-how-booze-travels-from-a-secret-room-to-your-glass/). They use compressed air - Cream (Baileys etc) they pour by hand, but they say it's because it's too thick to pump. Vaguely remember seeing a video on how they just pump cleaner through the lines to clean them periodically, can't find that though...Anyway, anything in contact with the alcohol should be food-grade.

Comment: When air is used to force the liquids out of their bottles, it should work with full as well as nearly empty bottles. No influence of air pressure and temperature changes and density and viscosity of the liquids. Volume should be precise, about +- 10 or 20 % and repeatable. No dripping of unused ingredients into the cocktail glas. Very small volumes of some few milliliters up to larger ones of some 100 ml.

Comment: @CraigC Baileys is likely not a newtonian fluid so making pumping it interesting...

Comment: @CraigC With enough pressure getting Baileys through the hose shouldn't be a problem. I could also use a bigger hose for the baileys.

Comment: Using enough pressure to force Baileys out of a half full bottle could be a problem at the end due to the remaining compressed air in the bottle.

Comment: Worst case I lose like 20ml of Baileys. But my hoses really aren't that long. And Baileys really isn't that thick. You can easily drink it through a normal straw...

Comment: I think I'd use those easy pour caps that you see in bars, put the bottles on a lazy susan, and have a bottle tipper in one spot.  This (A) seems to be an easier technical nut to crack, and (B) would be fun to watch.